# Which can be more appropriate expression?

Tags: phrase-usage

"I regret to inform you that...."

The above would be the beginning of a letter conveying

> (A) sad news
>                           (B) a denial
>   (C) an acceptance
>                  (D) an emergency

Comment: "I regret to inform you that..." "...your mother has died"; "...I didn't do it", "...I will be coming to the party"; "...I'm drowning". Which do you reckon?

Comment: Andrew leach# Is it sad news ?

Comment: What do you think the answer is, and why? Which of the options are you fairly sure *aren't* correct, and why? Show us what you think and what effort you put in. We're here to help, but not to do people's homework for them.

Comment: [*I regret to inform you that there is no reason for tears.*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=NazkJpZ9KRIC&pg=PA56&dq=%22I+regret+to+inform+you+that%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22I%20regret%20to%20inform%20you%20that%22&f=false) Poetry, that.

Comment: I regret to inform you that we don't do your homework for you.We might try and help you with it if you frame a question which shows what work you have done yourself and why your own researches haven't helped you to an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is (A) Sad News. The clue is the 'I regret' modifier to the delivery method 'Inform you' additionally it is usually used for some news/event that has already happened for which nothing can be done/changed.

In addition 'I regret' would mean the bearer of the new understands the significance and has some sympathy with the receiver. In common use this is not always the case as the phrase is usually part of a template designed to soften the blow so it's merely implied that the bearer understand the recipient would find the payload sad or disappointing.

Examples:
'I regret to inform you that you father passed away last night'
'I regret to inform you that we have chosen another candidate for the role'

It's not (B) a denial (it's it's denial of something the subject is likley to be sad or disappointed about) you don't normally regret to inform the subject of a denial unless the term is used as some sort of one-up-man-ship. 'I regret to inform you that I'm right and you're wrong' doesn't work in a truthful sense because clearly the bear doesn't regret anything. When someone or some entity denies something they do not normally regret denying or accepting it in the eyes of the subject. It's possible but less likely.

Its not (C) an acceptance unless it's acceptance of something the subject is likely to be sad/disappointed about. 'I regret to inform you that for 3 years I had an affair with your wife'... so the payload is acceptance (of a sort) but the regret modifier indicates the bearer understands the news is sad or disappointing.

It's not (D) an emergency because the phrase as a whole indicates there no hope for changing the news itself. In an emergency you would expect a less considered modifier indicating the urgency of the payload, there would be no regret as the events should not yet have come to pass

Answer (score -1):

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/regret
    Regret is also used to express in a polite way that you feel sorry about something:
[ + (that) clause ] My husband regrets (that) he couldn’t be here tonight.
[ + to infinitive ] The weather, I regret to say, is getting worse.

I think in your case of using,"i regret to inform you",is the polite form of use,so
,(A,B,C,D).are all valid in being used.